# how to remove JDBC debug logs

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

The following log is constantly thrown to the console:

```
09:36:53.456 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

09:36:53.456 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [0], value class [java.lang.Long], SQL type -5

09:36:53.456 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

09:36:53.472 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query

09:36:53.472 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement..

09:36:53.472 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

09:36:53.472 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [0], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type 2

09:36:53.472 [CloseConnectionsTimer] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

How can i stop these logs/Change the logging level to INFO or ERROR?

Comment: What kind of logging are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Anything less than debug level will make those logs disappear. eg. INFO, WARN, ERROR

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those are not JDBC logs, those are Spring logs.

Anyway, this should do the job in slf4j or log4j:

```
<logger name="org.spring.jdbc" level="OFF"/>
```